# Deleting default user database resource from Tomcat's default server.xml configuration file

Tags: java, tomcat

Tomcat's (8.0.27) **server.xml** file contains a default user database definition under global naming resources section:

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

Some scans discovered that **tomcat-users.xml** file contains plain text passwords. I am wondering whether this resource can be deleted? I am not planing to use this realm under my engine definition nor using the Tomcat manager application.

I didn't find any answer under Tomcat documentation section.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, if you also delete the Realm using this resource :

```
 <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
via a brute-force attack -->
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
<!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
resources under the key "UserDatabase". Any edits
that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
available for use by the Realm. -->
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Realm>
```

Be aware that doing this, you will need further configuration to user the manager app.